# Multiple receivers for messages (database field)

Tags: mysql, database-design, multiple-instances

i want to let users send each other messages,
For now this is the current schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inbox` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mensaje` varchar(250) collate utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `texto` text collate utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `visto` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `adjunto` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `item` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

For this question, i think it's only relevant:

- id_usuario - unique id from the user (sender)
- id_to      - unique id from the user (reciver)
- id         - unique message id

I'm wondering,

if I change 'id_to' type from integer (only one ID) to varchar, in order to:

- id_usuario - multiple unique ID's comma separated from users (recivers)

  and store multiple recivers like(multiple ID's): '333, 444, 555'

will I be able to:

- show each reciver the message?

Still figuring out the query, would it be something like:
`"select * from inbox where sesionid IN (idto)"` ??

- show sender each reciver for the message?
  Still figuring out the query, would it be something like `"select id_to from inbox where id = '254'"`
  And then explode by ',' ??

Or,

Should i change my scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing the size of your project, storing multiple ID's in one column is usually discouraged because of the processing power required to filter by each ID.

I would suggest creating a table called "MessageReceivers" or something like that.  It would contain the messageID and a userID for the person receiving the message.  You would create one row per recipient.

Then with indexes, you can quickly grab all the messages for that user with a simple join.

Comment: this way, i could exclude id_usuarios and id_to from 'inbox' and create inbox_map(id,id_from,id_to,msgid), or how? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this better by creating another table to store recipients, where each row lists the message ID and a recipient ID. Multiple rows for the same message ID would represent multiple recipients for the same message.

With this kind of structure, you can run queries with recipients using `JOIN` statements.